# Calculating first and second derivative the following

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$u(x)=\dfrac{1}{(\phi'(x))^l}v(t)$

where $t=\phi(x)$.

I calculate the first derivative as follows

$\dfrac{du}{dx}=((\phi'(x))^{-l})'v(t)+(\phi'(x))^{1-l}\dfrac{dv(t)}{dt}$

Is it right? 
And

$\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}=?$

Comment: Something seems missing in the first of the two terms on the right side of $\tfrac{du}{dx}$. A $\phi^{\prime\prime}$ should be there somewhere...

Comment: Also, $((\phi'(x))^{-l})' = -l*\phi''(x)*(\phi'(x))^{-l-1}$

Comment: Could you help me pls.